# The meaning of $\rm mHz$ and $\rm Hz^{1/2}$

Tags: frequency, units

If Hertz(Hz) is for once cycle per unit time what does mHz and $\sqrt{\text{Hz}}$ represents? I mean what is the physical manifestation of the a fractional power of a unit ?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a document where these are used in context? There are a few things that could be meant.

Comment: mHz is literally 0.001 Hz. Can you explain why're asking about mHz and sqrt Hz at the same time? One seems conceptually complex while the other does not.

Comment: Context means everything.  Please be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

this is a good question to ask the [electrical engineers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).  $\sqrt{\text{Hz}}$ is a unit you will see in a spec sheet for operational amplifiers and other analog parts.

[usually it's about a noise figure expressed as an additive voltage to the input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise).  so the unit is $\text{V}/\sqrt{\text{Hz}}$.  if you square it, you get $\text{V}^2/\text{Hz}$.  if you integrate that over the applicable bandwidth, you get $\text{V}^2$ and if you apply that to a 1 ohm resistor, you get watts.

Comment: I think this answer goes in the right direction but would be improved by explaining *why* noise power scales with frequency bandwidth.

Comment: Ditto for gravitational wave strain. The amplitude noise is expressed as Hz$^{-1/2}$. Same idea, it's the square root of the noise power per unit frequency.

Comment: oh dear.  but guys, i only do DSP${}^{*}$ nowadays.  i haven't designed or breadboarded an analog circuit for 4 decades.  ( ${}^{*}$ in fact, my life is so pathetic i am working solely in MATLAB.  i don't even do **real** DSP anymore. :-( .... )

Answer (score 1):

The millihertz is simply the inverse of a time period, 1000 s.  If a complete oscillation requires 1000 s, then the frequency of the oscillating system is 1 mHz. Or in 1 s the system moves through 0.001 of a complete cycle.

@robertbristow-johnson gives a succint answer for the $\sqrt{Hz}$

Comment: from your profile: *"Ph. D. in nuclear physics, Navy, first language = FORTRAN-IV, also coded DEC-10 assembly,...  motorcycle rider, classic Mustang driver, **Bible reader**, and getting older."*  $$ $$ likely not Bill Nye. :-)

Comment: i'm a failed PhD student - ABD in EE from the 80s, and my first language was also Fortran IV that i punched into a deck of cards.  i did a little DEC PDP-11 asm.  learned resently that the DEC-10 had an interesting floating-point format that is a little like IEEE-754 but using 2's complement instead of sign-magnitude.  kinda cool.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Indeed, likely not! LOL. Yeah, the DEC-10 bit me in the rear when I was doing quantum mechanical calculations. $h^2$ is well outside the range of the float-point values it could handle even at double-precision. I had to re-write a lot of calculations using logarithms.